# Wrong proof: in a ring $R$ such that $r^n=r$ for every $r\in R$, there are no non-trivial ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The claim is

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with an identity element $1\not=0$ with the property that for every $r\in R$ there is an $n\geq 2$ such that $r^n=r$. Then there are no non-trivial ideals.

My proof which I'm convinced must be wrong:

Let $r\in R/\{0\}$. Since $r^{n-1}r=r=rr^{n-1}$, and $1$ is unique, we must have $r^{n-1}=1$. Now let us look at the ideal $(r)=\{a\cdot r\mid a\in R\}$ of $R$. Since $r^{n-2}\in R$, then $r^{n-2}\cdot r= r^{n-1}=1\in(r)$. This implies that $(r) = R$.

Now let $I$ be an ideal of $R$ and suppose $I\not=\{0\}$. Then there is an element $r\in I$. We will show that $(r)\subseteq I$. Indeed, take $g\in(r)$. Then there is an element $a\in R$ such that $g = a\cdot r$. Since $I$ is an ideal, $g\in I$. Hence $(r) = R\subseteq I$, but this implies that $I = R$.

---

I am convinced this claim is wrong (and hence the proof must be too) since I am asked to solve an exercise which cannot be solved if this proposition is true.

Comment: The claim is indeed wrong: consider $R=\mathbb{F}_p \times \mathbb{F}_q$ for primes $p,q > 5$ and $n=(p-1)(q-1)+1$ works.

Comment: @Mindlack $p=q=n=2$ also works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How do you know that $R$ is an integral domain? We have $(r^{n-1}-1)r = 0,$ but that doesn't mean either $r = 0$ or $r^{n-1} = 1.$ You have only shown the result is true if $R$ is an integral domain.

Comment: Ah, I see. The claim that $r^{n-1} = 1$ simply isn't true. For example in $\mathbb{Z}_6$ we have $\bar{2}^3=\bar{8}=\bar{2}$. But $\bar{2}^2=\bar{4}$, which isn't $\bar{1}$. And this counterexample works because $\mathbb{Z}_6$ isn't an integral domain. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Consider the ring $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, in which $r^2=r$ for all $r$, but there are non-trivial ideals (e.g., the kernels of the projection to one of the summands).